# Cannot imoprt tensorflow on mac with python 2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow using pip, but when I try to import it I get error:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     21 from __future__ import print_function
     22 
---> 23 from tensorflow.python import *
     24 
     25 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 _default_dlopen_flags = sys.getdlopenflags()
     48 sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags)
     51 

ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow
```

I am running numpy version 1.11.3 and python version 2.7.9

Comment: What version of TensorFlow did you install?

Comment: @scai I'm not sure because I have to import tensorflow into python before checking for the version, which I cannot do. But I followed the direction given here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup

Comment: Here are a couple of things to try: 1) sudo pip uninstall six &&
sudo pip install six --upgrade --target="/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", 2) cd to a different directory and try again.

Comment: @scai I did that an now I'm getting: AttributeError: type object 'NewBase' has no attribute 'is_abstract'

Comment: This issue sounds similar to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1965. Please take a look at the solutions other people mentioned there.

Answer (score -1):

For **AttributeError: type object 'NewBase' has no attribute 'is_abstract'** (mentioned in comments)

Upgrading six will resolve the issue. TensorFlow requires [six => 1.10](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L41) - to check the six version, via interpreter:

```
$ python
>>>import six
>>>print six.\__version\__
```

Or, you can simply check it using pip:

```
$ pip show six
```

If you have six version less than 1.10, upgrade it:

```
$ pip install --upgrade six
```

---

Source: [Github thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1965).

Comment: I have six 1.10.0